# Determining the parameters of a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation, stochastic-approximation

Let's assume:

$$ay''(t)+by'(t)+cy(t)=f(t)$$

And we are given $n$ points $\{(t_1,y_1),(t_2,y_2),\ldots,(t_n,y_n)\}$, where $y_i=y(t_i)+\epsilon_i$.

By approximation of the differential equation, I mean finding some unknown parameters of the ordinary differential equation (ODE) itself and not the solution of the ODE.

My goal is to approximate $a,b,c$, such that $$\sum_i \|y(t_i)-y_i\|_2^2$$ is minimized.

Note 1: We might have extra constrains/approximations for $y''$ and $y'$. But those can be ignored in the first place.

Note 2: The objective  $\sum_i \|y(t_i)-y_i\|_2^2$  is just a tentative one, if there is any other criterion that results in some sort approximation of the ODE that would be okay as well.

Note 3: It is okay to assume $\epsilon_i$'s are all equal to zero, if this assumption simplifies the problem.

I tried to get some ideas by looking into the literature of stochastic differential equations (SDEs), but it seems like in the SDE's literature the focus is on the noisiness of the parameters. (Which I'm not sure if it's the case here.)

I know we may be able to solve the differential equation parametrically (i.e. finding $y(t)$ explicitly) and then approximate the parameters by numerically minimizing the summation: $\sum_i \|y(t_i)-y_i\|_2^2$. However, I'm trying not to do that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know $f(t)$? I think you will need to in order to solve for the other 3 parameters.

Comment: Yes, $f(t)$ is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added 13 Oct, better than the below:

Derivative estimates are very sensitive to noise in the data,
because high frequencies are amplified.
Non-uniform spacing makes this even worse --
dividing by $t_{i+1} - t_i \approx 0$ is a bad thing to do.
So don't do that then.
Instead, fit a [spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics))
to the data, a piecewise cubic with say 5 or 10 pieces. Then on each piece,
$\qquad spline(t) = a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + a_3 t^3 $
$\qquad spline'(t) = \qquad a_1 + 2 a_2 t + 3 a_3 t^2 $
$\qquad spline''(t) = \qquad\qquad  2 a_2 + 6 a_3 t $

Sample these on whatever grid you like -- the origial $t_i$, or a uniform grid.
(Bspline programs like [scipy.interpol.splev](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation-in-1-d-procedural-interpolate-splxxx) will do $spline'$ and $spline''$
too.)
Then you could fit $a\ b\ c$ with least squares.
Or, [Harmonic inversion](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Harminv)
looks nice (but I haven't used it):

> the FDM algorithm works by considering the time-series
>   to be the autocorrelation function of a fictitious dynamical system ...
>   For $M$ data points and $J$ frequencies, the time required is $O(M J) + O(J^3)$

---

First do the simpler case of $t_i = 1\ 2\ 3 ...$ equally spaced at integers.
Notation: call $y(t_i)\ y_i$, and the given data values $Y_i$ .
Approximate the derivatives with
[Finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference):
$\qquad y''_i \approx (y_{i+1} - 2 y_i + y_{i-1}) / 2 $
$\qquad y'_i \approx y_{i+1} - y_i \ \ $ or $(y_{i+1} - y_{i-1}) / 2 $
Then fitting the data
$\qquad Y_i \approx a\ (y_{i+1} - 2 y_i + y_{i-1}) / 2 \ + b\ (y_{i+1} - 2 y_i + y_{i-1}) / 2 \ + c\ y_i - f_i $
is a [Least_squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)
problem: set up an $n \times 3$ matrix $A$, and fit
$\qquad A x \approx Y - f,\ x = [a\ b\ c] $ .
(The first row of A needs $y_0 \approx y_1$,
and similarly the last row needs $y_{n+1} \approx y_n $ .)

Least squares is worth knowing about, because

- there are solid methods and programs
- it's easy to add constraints
- one can see outliers, way-off $Y_i$, and perhaps trim them
- it gives error bars / confidence intervals for $a\ b\ c$
  (if errors are normally distributed -- plot them).

---

Corrected 16 October (thanks @Alt):
splines, above, are much less sensitive to
$t_{i+1} - t_i \approx 0$ than using just 3 or 5 neighbours.
But if you must, here's how, in Python not equations.
The gist has a little test case.

```
""" approximate derivatives for non-uniformly spaced data
    deriv1, deriv2( x, t ) with t0 < t1 < ...
    Very sensitive to noise, or delta-t near 0
    Spline, then take derivatives, is much better; see scipy.interpolate.splev( der= )
"""
# http://google.com/search?q="finite-difference non-uniform site:stackexchange.com"

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

__version__ = "2015-10-18 oct  gist.github.com/denis-bz"

#...............................................................................
def deriv1( x, t ):
    return np.gradient(x) / np.gradient(t)  # (x+ - x-) / (t+ - t-)
    # return (ldiff(x) / ldiff(t)  +  rdiff(x) / rdiff(t)) / 2  ?

def deriv2( x, t ):
        # way off where delta-t is near 0
        # 5 neighbours, not 3
    return deriv1( deriv1( x, t ), t )
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I myself have come up with. The question that remains is the quality of approximation of the derivatives: especially for $y''$. And for $y'$, which of left or right approximations should be used.  I have--potentially--millions of data points, I thought if I search for the best points (i.e. closest $t_i$'s), then those ones may give a better approximation. But, I have no idea how sensitive the  final solution of ODE will be to the noise that I'm introducing in the coarse approximations. Do you have any idea about how I can approach the sensitivity analysis?

Comment: Left or right: take the average.
Sensitivity: look at the error bars aka standard errors in a b c. 
Plot the distributions of row errors A_i x - Y_i; trim outliers.
Take random subsets of the data, see how the a b c error bars vary.
Smooth: first take local averages { av t, av y },
e.g. (left + 4 val + right) / 6, before fitting.
(How will a b c be used, what's the real goal ?)

Comment: for $ y''(t_i)$ why not $y''(t_i) \approx (Rdiff_i - Ldiff_i)\ /\ (t_{i+1}-2t_i+t_{i-1})$ instead of $y''(t_i) \approx (Rdiff_i - Ldiff_i)\ /\ 2$?

Comment: Thanks @Alt. We're both wrong: your denominator is 0 for $t_i$ uniformly-spaced, correction coming .

Answer (score 1):

Its very hard to test, but this code should work. basically, I'm using a Matlab minimisation function and ODE solver, and finding the parameters that fit the data best.

```
%// Some sample data
X=0:0.1:4*pi;
YI=2*exp(-X/5).*cos(X)+0.2*rand(size(X));
f=@(x) cos(x);

%// Use a Matlab minimisation routine and ode45 to do the integration
CC=fminunc(@(C) norm(deval(ode45(@(x,y) [y(2);(f(x)-C(4)*y(2)-C(5)*y(1))/C(3)],X,C(1:2)),X,1)-YI),[1 1 1 1 1])

%// Plot the result
plot(X,YI,'o',linspace(min(X),max(X)),deval(ode45(@(x,y) [y(2);(f(x)-CC(4)*y(2)-CC(5)*y(1))/CC(3)],X,CC(1:2)),linspace(min(X),max(X)),1))

%// CC(1) is the initial condition for y(t) and CC(2) is the
%// initial condition for y'(t), there are found as part of
%// the minimisation
a=CC(3)
b=CC(4)
c=CC(5)
```

Which gives the following result
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to come up with an algorithmic solution, rather than a code that does the job though. Can you please explain a little bit how does this code mathematically work? Thanks again.

Comment: Really I'm just creating a function that calculates the norm of the difference between the target solution and the solution to the proposed ODE. Then I use `fminunc` to find the parameters that minimise the norm. You'd have to read the documentation to learn about the algorithms Matlab uses. I don't know of an algorithmic way of tdoing this though, sorry,

Comment: I noticed that, in the question I specified that "I know we may be able to solve the differential equation parametrically and then approximate the parameters by numerically minimizing the summation. However, I'm trying not to do that.". But thanks anyways :)

Comment: There is no parametric solution involved. Look, you can't expect an analytic solution to a fitting problem like this, there will always be a numerical component to solve, at best, a system of $n$ linear equations in 5 unknowns (you forgot about the initial conditions for your ODE). The only way you could improve on my solution is if you could write a general solution to the ODE, but the $f(t)$ makes that very hard. What would the solution you want, do better than the solution I've given?

Comment: I have mentioned that we have to consider the initial conditions (and other constraints)  later. $f(t)$ is either $\frac{1}{1+e^{-t}}$ or $tan^{-1}(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

This might not work well, but should for quite dense dataset $(x_k, y_k)$. You may approximate your data $(x_k, y_k)$ with a polynomial $P(x)$ and solve a least squares problem for $a,b,c$
$$
a P''(x_k) + b P'(x_k) + c P(x_k) = f(x_k),\quad  k = 1, \dots, n
$$

Here's a proof-of-concept Mathematica code (the true values are $a = 5, b = 3, c = -1$)

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]

X = RandomReal[{0, 5}, 100];
Y = y[X] /. First@NDSolve[{
      5 y''[x] + 3 y'[x] - y[x] == f[x], y[0] == 1, y[5] == 0
      }, y, {x, 0, 5}];

P = Fit[{X, Y}\[Transpose], Table[x^k, {k, 0, 10}], x]

(* 1. - 1.0688 x + 0.420601 x^2 - 0.0863036 x^3 + 
 0.0197967 x^4 - 0.00477045 x^5 + 0.000538399 x^6 - 
 6.30857 * 10^-6 x^7 - 1.91958 * 10^-6 x^8 - 
 7.73332 * 10^-8 x^9 + 1.36073 * 10^-8 x^10 *)

LeastSquares[Table[{
   D[P, x, x] /. x -> z,
   D[P, x] /. x -> z,
   P /. x -> z
   }, {z, X}], f[X]]

(* {5.00004, 3.00023, -0.999674} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! In my problem it is important to avoid any model assumption and parametrization. I see how polynomial assumption simplifies the problem to just a linear least-squares parameter estimation, but this is some thing that I have to avoid. Because, on the hindsight, I know that the expected solution might be way more complicated, and polynomials are not good extrapolator in my case.